# My Brand New Nikon 50mm f/1.8D giving problem

Tags: nikon, aperture, 50mm

My lens is Nikkor 50mm f1.8D and camera is Nikon D7000. I bought the lens yesterday. (24.09.2013) In spite of setting the lens aperture locked at f22, as recommended, my Nikon D7000 camera apertures are not changing in ANY modes. (Manual, Aperture Priority, Shutter Priority) I have to unlock the Aperture lock of the lens and rotate it every time to change Aperture value. Is the lens defective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The D7000 has a custom setting that allows you to use either the camera or the aperture ring on a 'D' lens to select the aperture. For the camera to control the aperture, be sure you have selected *Sub-command dial* (and not *Aperture ring*) in the *Custom Settings menu-->f6: Customize Command Dials-->Aperture setting*. It is on page 233 of your [D7000 User's Manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D7000_ENnoprint.pdf). If *Aperture ring* is selected then the D7000 will behave as you have described in your question.

Comment: Tons of thanks Michael Clark. Found the setting and did the correction. Now it works fine and will explore this lovely lens as soon as possible. Thanks again.