# Nikon F - Lens with Built-in Autofocus Motor and Manual Aperture Ring

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, aperture

My question is as follows, is there such thing as a nikon-f mount lens that has a built in autofocus motor and a manual aperture ring? Or do the two contradict each other? The camera model is Nikon d3300. Any lens brand would be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few AF-S Nikon "D" lenses (And older AF-I "D" lenses) that feature both aperture rings and focus motors in the lens. But your D3300 does not allow using the aperture ring on the lens to control the aperture. For that you need an [option](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42922/my-brand-new-nikon-50mm-f-1-8d-giving-problem/42925#42925) found only on higher tiered Nikon bodies.

Most AF-S "D" lenses are larger lenses with longer focal lengths. The focus elements in such lenses are heavier than most "D" lenses and would require gearing that would make them painfully slow to focus using the focus motor built in to some Nikon camera bodies. The [AF-S NIKKOR 300mm f/4D IF-ED](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005LEOM) is one such lens. Most of the others have focal lengths of 400mm and up. There is also the [AF-S Zoom-Nikkor 17-35mm f/2.8D ED-IF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005LEOS). The [Nikon AF-S Zoom-Nikkor 28-70mm f/2.8D IF-ED](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005LEOR) is now discontinued. The [AF-S Zoom-Nikkor 80-200mm f/2.8D ED](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/telephotozoom/af-s_zoom80-200mmf_28d_if/) has long been out of production as well.

Comment: And in the context of the sentence that you are nitpicking "the lens" is *whatever lens* happens to be attached to a D3300.